# Why doesn't CSS properties work properly with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So:

1. I just tried to use loops to add a background color and a border to each element in class .readtrue or .readfalse, but then somehow the last element, even though it changed class like the others, did not change the border or background color.
2. Then I tried to add something in Javascript that would just add `<style> </style>` element to `<head> </head>`, but according to a console error the `<head> </head>` element does not exist, although checking the information about the page this item exists.
3. Then I just tried to change the properties of these classes in a separate CSS file, but it had no effect.

That's why I'm here. I'm a Javascript beginner and have no idea how to change the background color so that the browser will say it's worth showing.

```
    if (val.read === true) {
                div.setAttribute('class', 'readtrue')
               } else {
                div.setAttribute('class', 'readfalse')
              }
```

val is an object with the 'read' attribute and depending on whether 'read' is true or false, div class should change.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are getting the variable `div` but a simple example for what you want to achieve is as follows.

*I have commented the code, if you need more clarity, kindly comment on this answer.*

```js
function toggleBackgroundColors() {
  // Fetch all the elements which has 'element' as a class
  var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
  // Loop through all the fetched elements
  for(var i =0 ; i < spans.length;i++) {
    var element = spans[i]; // assign a single element
    // Check if the element already has a 'bgColor' class
    if(element.className.includes("bgColor","")) {
      // If it does, simply remove it
      element.className = element.className.replace("bgColor","");
    }
    else {
      // If it does not, simply add it
      element.className += " bgColor";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* basic styling for the element */
.element {
width:20px;
height:20px;
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid #000;
background-color:blue;
}

/* color class you want to add */
.bgColor {
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span class="element"></span>
<span class="element"></span>
<span class="element"></span>
<span class="element"></span>
<span class="element"></span>
</div>

<button onclick="toggleBackgroundColors()">toggle color</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I just tried to use loops to add a background color and a border to each element in class .readtrue or .readfalse, but then somehow the last element, even though it changed class like the others, did not change the border or background color.

It's possible you have another styling overriding your class's style on the last element. Bootstrap and css pseudo-classes like `:hover` are the usual culprits. Use your browser developer tools and append your class's style with !important, like so `background-color: yourColor !important;` to test it out.
You could also be adding both classes

> 2. Then I tried to add something in Javascript that would just add   element to  , but according to a console error the   element does not exist, although checking the information about the page this item exists.

The correct way to query an element by tag name is `document.querySelector("head")` or `$("head")` in jQuery, but jQuery returns a jQuery Object so you dereference it by doing `[0]`

**BUT**

Using JavaScript to append a `<style>` element to the `<head>` section of your page is horrible practice. Please just add the styling through a reference to a style sheet on the actual HTML.